# Chess training method

Tags: method, chess, training

Can I get a patent for a chess game training method that involves a specific approach to the learning process? If possible what will be the cost?

Best regards,
Grigor

Comment: You need to specify what countries you want to get patents in.

Comment: Please don't use answers to express thanks. As you gain reputation you will gain the ability to comment. In the mean time accepting an answer as you have is the best way to thank the answerer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In much of the world (Europe is an example) a patent must be for a technical solution to a technical problem. A method of teaching chess might or might not be technical but it is not a technical problem so it would not be possible to get a patent for it in any such juristiction.

In the U.S. there is no such requirement. You might look at [US6120029A](https://patents.google.com/patent/US6120029A)  *Educational game for teaching chess through example*.  To be patentable your method will need to be something that can survive being labeled as "abstract" or more specifically a "method of organizing human activity", neither of which has been defined.

An answer I posted to a question  [Can teaching methods be patented?](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/759/can-teaching-methods-be-patented) in 2014 -

> To directly answer part of your question - yes methods of teaching can be patented. I did a quick search in the class that covers educational devices (434) and had over 5000 hits of patents with the word "method" in at least one claim. Also searched for any patent with both method and teaching in the clam wording. About 1000 hits.

Estimates for cost to get a U.S. patent might be $5k-$20k for searching, drafting and applying + $3k - $6 for prosecution assuming no need for an appeal to the board. If appeal to the board needed, add $4k-$10k. Using a registered patent agent vs a patent attorney might help you stay on the lower end of the ranges.

If you dedicated yourself to learning patent law and patent office procedures over several months and did it as a pro se, the fees would add up to about $1,000 if you are a micro entity and about $2000 if a small entity.

Comment: A short comment on the cost of pursuing a patent would fully answer the OP.